# ResumeData getting nil when using downloadTaskWithRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsmutableurlrequest, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

If I'm using this below code

```
aDownloadTask = [self.backgroundSession downloadTaskWithURL:aRemoteURL];
```

`Desc of above code:`
When I started download by using **downloadTaskWithURL** It’s return **expectedContentLength negative(-1)** But that time resume data getting perfectly.

**Another one is**
For solved above problem I'm using this below code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *aURLRequest = nil;
aURLRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:aRemoteURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[aURLRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[aURLRequest setValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

aDownloadTask=[self.backgroundSession downloadTaskWithRequest:aURLRequest];
```

`Desc of above code:` Using above code expectedContentLength getting perfectly. But issue is the  when pause downloading resume data nil every time.

Thats why my downloading start from beginning and not from that point when I pause.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please , remove this below line from your code and try. Your resume data will getting perfectly.

```
[aURLRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```